# Datagrid filter / sort on column based on function

Tags: vmware-clarity

I have a Clarity v2 data grid with built in sorting / filtering. This works for columns populated by a property via interpolation. However it does not work if the column is populated by a method call via interpolation.

I'm assuming, that because there is a method call, the value is not available to the grid upon initial binding... but I'm hoping there's a way around this.

```
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Id'">ID</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Client'">Client</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Name'" [clrDgSortOrder]="ClrDatagridSortOrder.ASC">Name</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'PublicKeyHash'">Public Key Hash</clr-dg-column>

  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let clientLicense of ClientLicenses" [clrDgItem]="clientLicense">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.Id}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>
      {{getClientName(clientLicense.ClientId)}}
    </clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.Name}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.PublicKeyHash}}</clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>
```

Also - what if we have a complex cell, i.e. a tool tip such as the following?

```
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Id'">ID</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Client'">Client</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'Name'" [clrDgSortOrder]="ClrDatagridSortOrder.ASC">Name</clr-dg-column>
  <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'PublicKeyHash'">Public Key Hash</clr-dg-column>

  <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let clientLicense of ClientLicenses" [clrDgItem]="clientLicense">
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.Id}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>
      <clr-tooltip>
        <span clrTooltipTrigger>{{getClientName(clientLicense.ClientId)}}</span>
        <clr-tooltip-content clrPosition="top-right" clrSize="lg" *clrIfOpen>
          <span>Client ID: {{clientLicense.ClientId}}</span>
        </clr-tooltip-content>
      </clr-tooltip>
    </clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.Name}}</clr-dg-cell>
    <clr-dg-cell>{{clientLicense.PublicKeyHash}}</clr-dg-cell>
  </clr-dg-row>
```

Comment: Ah, in hindsight, it might be the custom sort / filter capabilities of the grid... I'll investigate this and answer this question if that is the solution.

https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/custom-sorting
https://v2.clarity.design/datagrid/custom-filtering

Comment: Yeah, The custom filter will be the way to go here. It will give you full control of the filtering. Post herenn BJ is you run into any issues making it work.

Answer (score 0):

Use of custom sorting / filtering solves this issue.

- v2.clarity.design/datagrid/custom-sorting
- v2.clarity.design/datagrid/custom-filtering